# ubuntu error : Errors were encountered while processing: redis-server

Tags: process, redis

I am getting error when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`

**output error :**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up redis-server (5:4.0.9-1) ...
dpkg-statoverride: error: user 'redis' does not exist
dpkg: error processing package redis-server (--configure):
 installed redis-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2

Errors were encountered while processing:
 redis-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

the error about redis-server and can not remove redis-server.

my linux is ubuntu 18 Desktop.

Answer (score 5):

You should probably alter the redis.conf file to force it to use IPv4 if it supports that mode only and then maybe you could run it without IPv6.

```
nano /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Simply remove the `::1` IPv6 loopback address from the bind config option:

```
- bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
+ bind 127.0.0.1
```

Now redis will not try to use the IPv6 network.

Try to install again

```
apt install redis-server
```

Test the Redis Instance Functionality
To test that your service is functioning correctly, connect to the Redis server with the command-line client:

```
redis-cli
```

In the prompt that follows, test connectivity by typing:

ping
You should see:

```
$ 127.0.0.1:6379> ping
```

Output

```
PONG
```

Check that you can set keys by typing:

```
$ 127.0.0.1:6379> set test "It's working!"
```

Output

```
OK
```

Now, retrieve the value by typing:

```
$ 127.0.0.1:6379> get test
```

You should be able to retrieve the value we stored:

Output

$ 127.0.0.1:6379> "It's working!"

Exit the Redis prompt to get back to the shell:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
```

As a final test, let's restart the Redis instance:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart redis
```

Comment: Saved my ass !!!

Comment: And mine too...